# Executing a user-mode executable from kernel-mode

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, kernel-mode, usermode

I'm building a HW-simulator for our driver team. Now, the simulator is devided in to 2 modules:
First module runs inside the driver, in kernel mode and  that's where the main interface between the driver and the HW-Simulator.
Second module is an executable user-mode code which generates data for the simulator and transports it to the simulator via calls to `DeviceIOControl` (under windows API)

My need is this: I want to be able to execute the user-mode executable from within the kernel-mode. And I need to be able to do this in a relatively portable way. Currently I'm only running on Windows, but that should change soon.
Further more, I need to be able to communicate with the user-mode code via it's`stdin` pipe, in order to reconfigure it and eventually close it.

I found this:
[Executing a user-space function from the kernel space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246636/executing-a-user-space-function-from-the-kernel-space)

but it's only relevant for the linux-kernel. Is there a more portable alternative? Or a windows alternative?

Can I do this in Windows by simply using the ShellExecute/RunAs API functions?

Note: We are aware of the security risks involved in invoking user-mode code from the kernel-space. But as this is only meant to be used as a test-environment and will not ever reach our release code, then we are not concerned.

Comment: I doubt that you will find a "portable" way of doing kernel-level stuff.

Comment: @casablanca: fair enough. How do I accomplish this in windows then?

Comment: Oh, I don't know the answer myself, that was just a comment. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a clean way to do this in the Windows kernel. The user-mode API [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create processes use undocumented APIs ([NtCreateProcess](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Process/NtCreateProcess.html)/[NtCreateThread](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/NtCreateThread.html)) to create a process.

The recommended thing to do would be to have a "partner service", a user-mode service that communicates with your driver using IOCTL. You can use the [inverted call model](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=94) to have your driver call your service to have it create a process.

Answer (score 0):

Really, there is no documented way to do it without triggering process creation from user-mode.

But there is one undocumented tricky way if You don't want to create user-mode application:

To create a valid win32 process the driver must communicate with CSRSS (what is undocumented).

You can enqueue a user-mode APC, allocate some virtual memory for the APC code in the context of any existing process. This code should simply call CreateProcess and anything else You want.