# How to use system() in a kernel module as stdlib.h cannot be used in a kernel program?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

When developing a kernel module in Linux, using the C standard library isn't allowed. However, in case I need to use some common functionality like `system()`, how do I implement this?

Comment: Accessing `system` in low-level underlying kernel code sounds paradoxical.

Comment: system does a fork and executes a shell to run the command, neither of which makes sense in the kernel.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve. This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: If you really want to run user mode software through the kernel, you could look at how core dumping to a process, or usermode driver support work, using `call_usermodehelper` and friends.

Comment: Actually I am trying to use a kernel module for displaying the information regarding the kernel using the system call but unable to do so. Is there any other way i can show info using c program i,e. kernal module only?

Comment: The Linux kernel produces output to user-space through its log `printk`, `dmesg`, virtual files like those in `/proc` and `/sys` and device ioctls (IO Control, the `ioctl` system call). Oh, and `NETLINK` sockets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute shell command in kernel programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676667/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-kernel-programming)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is: ***you don't***. There are very, very few instances in which you would need to do something similar to `system()`, that is to call a user-space application from kernel space. In those special cases, there is the [usermode-helper API](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/umh.c#L629) available, which allows launching (and possibly waiting for) arbitrary user space programs from kernel space.

However, it must be noted that when designing a module you should really avoid being dependent on the output/execution of other user space programs. In the best case scenario, this slows the system down, while in the worst case it can also break kernel/user space isolation and introduce critical vulnerabilities. The existing instances of usage of the `call_usermodehelper()` function in modern kernel versions can almost be [counted on the tips of your hands](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/C/ident/call_usermodehelper). You will basically never need to do such a thing when writing a kernel module. If you think you do, you should re-think about it twice first.

Comment: Actually I am trying to use a kernel module for displaying the information regarding the kernel using the system call but unable to do so. Is there any other way i can show info using c program i,e. kernal module only?

Comment: @Suyash25 that is a very broad and unclear situation. You should detail what you are trying to accomplish as much as possible, then post another question showing your attempt along with the rest of the information.

Comment: Sounds like the kernel should offer the info through /sys and a user space program should read it.